# Zend Framework Render Barcodes Into Multiple PDF Pages with other content

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, barcode

I am trying to create pages of incrementing labels that include barcodes.  I can get a barcode into a PDF, and I can get it superimposed on other content in the PDF (see below). But I can't figure out how to assign a barcode to a certain page of a pdf using something maybe like

```
Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'pdf',
$barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->setResource($page)->draw();
```

or

```
$page = Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'pdf', $barcodeOptions,
$rendererOptions)->setResource($pdf)->draw();
```

Both of the above snippets cause errors when set in the context of my larger code.  Further down is code that renders with no errors, but doesn't give me what I need.

This question is identical to [Zend Framework Render Barcodes Into PDF Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049046/zend-framework-render-barcodes-into-pdf-pages), which never reached a working answer from what I can see.

First, to get this to work, I copied the Zend version 1.11 Barcode library into my Zend version 1.7.2 library folder.  I also copied a free non-monospaced font into my application/library as the code shows.

I can create a multi-page PDF of labels.  And I can put a barcode in a PDF.  What I can't do is put barcodes on multiple pages.  I'll show what I am doing, and hopefully you can tell me what I am doing wrong or need to do.

First I have this little snippet that puts a barcode in a PDF:

```
// A font path is mandatory for Barcode Pdf output.  
// This application defines ROOT_DIR in index.php.  Others may define APPLICATION_PATH.
// Monospaced fonts apparently don't work here.
$barcodeOptions = array(
    'text' => '11111',
    'font' => ROOT_DIR . '/library/Rbs/Barcode/FreeSerif.ttf'
);
$rendererOptions = array(
    'topOffset' => 50,
    'leftOffset' => 50
);
Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'pdf',
$barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->setResource($pdf)->draw();
```

Then I have this (long) code that creates labels. I've commented below near the bottom the two main places I have experimented putting the barcode, but the core problem seems to be that I don't know how to put a barcode on a certain page of a PDF:

```
    public function labelsAction()
    {

        $request['starting_label_number'] = '100001';
        $request['label_count'] = 32;

        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

        $filename= 'files/inventory_labels.pdf';
        $form['units_name'] = 'inches';
        $form['units_factor'] = 72;
        $form['margin_bottom'] = 0.5;
        $form['margin_left'] = 0.19;
        $form['label_width'] = 2.625;
        $form['label_height'] = 1.0;
        $form['label_spacing_column'] = 0.125;
        $form['label_margin'] = 0.1;
        $form['label_column_count'] = 3;
        $form['label_row_count'] = 10;

        try 
        {
            // create PDF
            $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();

            // define font resource
            $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_ROMAN);

            $total_pages = ceil($request['label_count'] / ($form['label_column_count'] * $form['label_row_count']));
            $current_label_number = $request['starting_label_number'];

            // Create each page
            for ($page_number = 1; $page_number <= $total_pages; $page_number++)
            {

                // create A4 page
                $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_LETTER);

                // write text to page
                // Fill up each page with labels or blanks
                for ($row = 1; $row <= $form['label_row_count']; $row++)
                {
                    for ($column = 1; $column <= $form['label_column_count']; $column++)
                    {
                        if ($current_label_number - $request['starting_label_number'] < $request['label_count'])
                        {

                            $label_center_y = 
                                (
                                    $form['margin_bottom'] 
                                    + ($form['label_row_count'] - $row + 0.5) * $form['label_height']
                                ) * $form['units_factor'];
                            $label_center_x = 
                                (
                                    $form['margin_left'] 
                                    + ($column - 0.5) * $form['label_width'] 
                                    + ($column - 1) * $form['label_spacing_column']
                                ) * $form['units_factor'];

                            // Get our bearings $xleft, $ybottom, $xright, $ytop, $filltype
                            $page->drawRectangle(
                                $label_center_x - $form['label_width'] * $form['units_factor'] / 2, 
                                $label_center_y - $form['label_height'] * $form['units_factor'] / 2,
                                $label_center_x + $form['label_width'] * $form['units_factor'] / 2, 
                                $label_center_y + $form['label_height'] * $form['units_factor'] / 2,
                                Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE
                            );

                            // define image resource
                            $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('images/new/logo.jpg');

                            // write image to page $xleft, $ybottom, $xright, $ytop
                            $image_width = 125;
                            $image_height = 30;
                            $image_y_offset = 13;
                            $page->drawImage(
                                $image, 
                                $label_center_x - $image_width / 2, 
                                $label_center_y - $image_height / 2 + $image_y_offset,
                                $label_center_x + $image_width / 2, 
                                $label_center_y + $image_height / 2 + $image_y_offset
                            );
                            $text_width = 108;
                            $page->setFont($font, 10)
                               ->drawText('www.pristineauction.com', $label_center_x - $text_width / 2, $label_center_y - 10);
                            $text_width = 68;
                            $page->setFont($font, 22)
                               ->drawText($current_label_number, $label_center_x - $text_width / 2, $label_center_y - 32);
                            $current_label_number += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

/* If I insert the barcode creator here inside the label loop, I get a barcode all by itself on the first PDF page, with labels following on subsequent pages.  Not bad, but not right. */                
                    // add page to document
                    $pdf->pages[] = $page;
                }

/* If I insert the barcode creator here outside the label loop, I get a barcode superimposed on the first PDF page.  Not bad, but not in page loop, and not repeating. */                
                // save as file
                $pdf->save($filename);
                $this->_redirect('/' . $filename);
            } catch (Zend_Pdf_Exception $e) {
                die ('PDF error: ' . $e->getMessage());  
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                die ('Application error: ' . $e->getMessage());    
            }
        }
```

Comment: Again, I CAN print a single page of labels with barcodes, images, lines, and text on them using the code given plus a second loop for the barcodes.  But any additional pages I print get the very same barcodes on them.  Is there a Barcode to pdf pageoffset or anything like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found the answer, thanks to Javier Bracero at http://javierbracero.blogspot.com/2012/01/zend-generate-pdf-including-list-of.html

You can supply page index as an argument! Very nice to finally know that.

The good parts:

```
// Create Pdf definition
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
// Define font resource for Pdf library
$font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_ROMAN);

// Must set a TTF for Barcode library
// This application defines ROOT_DIR in index.php.  Others may define APPLICATION_PATH.
Zend_Barcode::setBarcodeFont(ROOT_DIR . '/library/Rbs/Barcode/FreeSerif.ttf');

// Create the Pdf library elements for each page and add it to the document 
// before printing the Barcode elements onto that page
for ($page_index = 0; $page_index <= $last_page_index; $page_index++)
{
    // create a new Pdf page
    $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_LETTER);

    // write Pdf elements to the page

    // add page to document
    $pdf->pages[] = $page;
}

// Add barcodes to each page after it is added.
for ($page_index = 0; $page_index <= $last_page_index; $page_index++)
{
    $barcodeOptions = array(
        'text' => $current_label_number
    );
    $rendererOptions = array(
        'topOffset' => $label_center_y + 3,
        'leftOffset' => $label_center_x + 12
    );
    Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'pdf',
    $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->setResource($pdf, $page_index)->draw();
    $current_label_number += 1;
}

// save as file
$pdf->save($filename);
```

The whole label maker:

```
// By Tom Haws 2012-10-03
// Prints labels with barcodes to pdf
public function labelsAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    $request['start_number'] = max(1, $this->_request->getParam('start-number'));
    $request['label_count'] = $this->_request->getParam('label-count');
    $inventory_number = $request['start_number'];
    $filename= 'files/inventory_labels.pdf';
    $form['units_name'] = 'inches';
    $form['units_factor'] = 72;
    $form['margin_top'] = 0.5;
    $form['margin_bottom'] = 0.5;
    $form['margin_left'] = 0.19;
    $form['label_width'] = 2.625;
    $form['label_height'] = 1.0;
    $form['label_spacing_column'] = 0.125;
    $form['label_margin'] = 0.1;
    $form['label_column_count'] = 3;
    $form['label_row_count'] = 10;

    $last_page_index = ceil($request['label_count'] / ($form['label_column_count'] * $form['label_row_count'])) - 1;
    $current_label_number = $request['start_number'];

    try 
    {
        // Create PDF
        $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
        // Define font resource for Pdf library
        $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_ROMAN);

        // Must set a TTF for Barcode library
        Zend_Barcode::setBarcodeFont(ROOT_DIR . '/library/Rbs/Barcode/FreeSerif.ttf');

        // Create the Pdf library elements for each page and add it to the document 
        // before printing the Barcode elements onto that page
        for ($page_index = 0; $page_index <= $last_page_index; $page_index++)
        {
            // create the new Pdf page
            $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_LETTER);
            // write Pdf elements to the page
            // Fill up each page with labels or blanks
            for ($row = 1; $row <= $form['label_row_count']; $row++)
            {
                for ($column = 1; $column <= $form['label_column_count']; $column++)
                {
                    if ($current_label_number - $request['start_number'] < $request['label_count'])
                    {
                        // Note that Pdf library uses a coordinate system with origin at bottom left
                        $label_center_y = 
                            (
                                $form['margin_bottom'] 
                                + ($form['label_row_count'] - $row + 0.5) * $form['label_height']
                            ) * $form['units_factor'];
                        $label_center_x = 
                            (
                                $form['margin_left'] 
                                + ($column - 0.5) * $form['label_width'] 
                                + ($column - 1) * $form['label_spacing_column']
                            ) * $form['units_factor'];

                        // Draw a design guidance frame for each label.
                        // $xleft, $ybottom, $xright, $ytop, $filltype
                        /*
                        $page->drawRectangle(
                            $label_center_x - $form['label_width'] * $form['units_factor'] / 2, 
                            $label_center_y - $form['label_height'] * $form['units_factor'] / 2,
                            $label_center_x + $form['label_width'] * $form['units_factor'] / 2, 
                            $label_center_y + $form['label_height'] * $form['units_factor'] / 2,
                            Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE
                        ); */

                        // define image resource
                        $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('images/new/logo.jpg');

                        // write image to page $xleft, $ybottom, $xright, $ytop
                        $image_width = 125;
                        $image_height = 30;
                        $image_y_offset = 20;
                        $page->drawImage(
                            $image, 
                            $label_center_x - $image_width / 2, 
                            $label_center_y - $image_height / 2 + $image_y_offset,
                            $label_center_x + $image_width / 2, 
                            $label_center_y + $image_height / 2 + $image_y_offset
                        );
                        $text_width = 108;
                        $page->setFont($font, 10)
                           ->drawText('www.pristineauction.com', $label_center_x - $text_width / 2, $label_center_y - 1);
                        $text_width = 68;
                        $page->setFont($font, 22)
                           ->drawText($current_label_number, $label_center_x - 72, $label_center_y - 25);
                        $current_label_number += 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            // add page to document
            $pdf->pages[] = $page;
        }

        // Add barcodes to pages of document.
        $current_label_number = $request['start_number'];
        for ($page_index = 0; $page_index <= $last_page_index; $page_index++)
        {
            for ($row = 1; $row <= $form['label_row_count']; $row++)
            {
                for ($column = 1; $column <= $form['label_column_count']; $column++)
                {
                    // Note that barcodes use a coordinate system with origin at top left
                    $label_center_y = 
                        (
                            $form['margin_top'] 
                            + ($row - 0.5) * $form['label_height']
                        ) * $form['units_factor'];
                    $label_center_x = 
                        (
                            $form['margin_left'] 
                            + ($column - 0.5) * $form['label_width'] 
                            + ($column - 1) * $form['label_spacing_column']
                        ) * $form['units_factor'];

                    // A font path is mandatory for Barcode Pdf output.  
                    // This application defines ROOT_DIR in index.php.  Others may define APPLICATION_PATH.
                    $barcodeOptions = array(
                        'text' => $current_label_number
                    );
                    $rendererOptions = array(
                        'topOffset' => $label_center_y + 3,
                        'leftOffset' => $label_center_x + 12
                    );
                    Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'pdf',
                    $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->setResource($pdf, $page_index)->draw();
                    $current_label_number += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        // save as file
        $pdf->save($filename);
        $this->_redirect('/' . $filename);
    } catch (Zend_Pdf_Exception $e) {
        die ('PDF error: ' . $e->getMessage());  
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die ('Application error: ' . $e->getMessage());    
    }
}
```